# rspec2 routing error for index page [Rails3, Rspec2]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rails-routing

I have the following resource (config/routes.rb)

```
resources :dashboard

dashboard_index GET    /dashboard(.:format)           dashboard#index
                         POST   /dashboard(.:format)           dashboard#create
           new_dashboard GET    /dashboard/new(.:format)       dashboard#new
          edit_dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id/edit(.:format)  dashboard#edit
               dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id(.:format)       dashboard#show
                         PUT    /dashboard/:id(.:format)       dashboard#update
                         DELETE /dashboard/:id(.:format)       dashboard#destroy
```

and I have the following controller spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe DashboardController do

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

and when I run the spec I'm keep on getting the following error

```
Failures:

  1) DashboardController GET 'index' returns http success
     Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"dashboard"}
     # ./spec/controllers/dashboard_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.12126 seconds
```

when I check for similar questions, almost all of them are because not passing required parameters, but in my case my action does not expect a parameter,  so what would be the missing part here

I'm on

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
end
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running spork or anything else that might not be picking up changes to routes.rb?

Comment: @JohnNaegle, yes you are right, my bad ;(, I was using spork + guard and seems like its not picking up the routes.rb. thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: Been there, done that ;)

Answer (score 0):

as @John Naegle pointed out, it appears to be a problem with my spork + guard setup and its not picking up the 'routes.rb' file

Sorry for the confusion